# Connectivity problems in a topology

Tags: network, protocol-theory, networking, topology

I cannot identify any network problems in the following topology.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ae2e.jpg

Any help in identifying problems would be appreciated, and I would be happy to work on them.

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of duplicate IPs
A couple of no IPs
A couple of DGs in the wrong subnet....Does that matter?

Comment: Thanks! Where is the no IP's? The other topology problems I understand

Comment: Letter..Kenny..